# Approximating eps-homomorphisms

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. A map $\rho:G\rightarrow U_n$ is called an $\epsilon$-homomorphism if and only if for any $g,h\in G$, we have $||\rho(g)\rho(h)-\rho(gh)||\leq \epsilon$ where the $||$ norm is the usual operator norm. Kazhdan proves in his [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02761236) that for $\epsilon < 1/1000$ and any $\epsilon$-homomorphism $\rho$ there is a homomorphism $\pi:G\rightarrow U_n$ such that $||\pi-\rho|| \leq O(\epsilon)$. Can you prove a similar statement if we replace operator norm by Hilbert-Schmidt norm?

This is what I mean. Suppose $\epsilon_0$ is a sufficiently small number which doesn't depend on n or $G$. Let $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$. Assume that $\rho:G\rightarrow U_n$ is an $n \epsilon$-homomorphism in the Hilbert-Schmidt sense i.e. for any $g,h\in G$ arithmetic mean of singular values of $\rho(g)\rho(h)-\rho(gh)$ is less than $\epsilon$. Can we prove that $\rho$ has distance at most $n O(\epsilon)$ from an exact homomorphism in the Hilbert-Schmidt sense?

Comment: Did you try to follow his argument using HS norm instead?

Comment: Kazhdan's proof doesn't work in the HS norm. Here is the proof. Let $W(g,h)=\rho(g)\rho(h)\rho(gh)^{-1}$. As $W(g,h)$ is close to identity matrix in the operator norm, $\log W(g,h)$ is well-defined. Let $\alpha(g,h)=\log W(g,h)$. Define:

$$\rho_1(g)= \rho(g)\exp( - E_h\ \rho(g)  \alpha (g,h)  \rho(g)^{-1})$$

So $\rho_1$ is a $5\epsilon^2$-homomorphism. Therefore $\rho_n$ converges to an exact homomorphism.

In the HS sense, $\log W(g,h)$ is not well-defined anymore as $I-W(g,h)$ can have few large singular values. The calculation doesn't imply that $\rho_1$ is a $5\epsilon^2$-homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to add that the answer to above question is yes:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04085